# (macOS) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in NetBeans 12.4

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I know this question has been asked before, but most of the information I can find is about Windows and the instructions are different enough that things get confusing. I should probably add that I am not very experienced with a Mac, nor Java.

I'm trying to get my Java program to connect to my MySQL database. I think the code is right, but I'm having trouble getting NetBeans to register the .jar file.

I've tried to manually add the library to NetBeans already, although it didn't seem to work. I also tried adding the location of the .jar to the Java CLASSPATH.

On some of the advice I've read, it said that the my-sql-connector folder should be in the /lib/ folder, although I'm not sure where to find that, or if it even applies to Mac. I tried looking in the NetBeans package files for it, but couldn't see anything.

EDIT: Updating with my code...

```
    Connection conn;
    Statement st;
    
    public DatabaseConnect() 
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://3306/DungeonsAndDragons", "root", "*******");
            st = conn.createStatement();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Failed to connect to the database. " + e);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: >On some of the advice I've read, it said that the my-sql-connector folder should be in the /lib/ folder, although I'm not sure where to find that, or if it even applies to Mac. < It *does* apply to MacOS. It should be under your project root directory, and yes, you should put the driver jar there. Don't confuse that with the distribution archive

Comment: @g00se There are only two folders in the project root directory, src and target. I placed the .jar file in the root and tried again though, and got the same error.

Comment: >I placed the .jar file in the root< No. Place it in the lib directory below your project

Answer (score 1):

hi you can use brew for install mysql connector.
copy and past commands in your terminall

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

brew update

brew tap gbeine/homebrew-java

brew install mysql-connector-java
```

you can read more about it in github:
https://github.com/gbeine/homebrew-java

and add this dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.25</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I tried to install this, then I cleaned and built the project, and then ran it. I am still getting the same error though. Is there another step I am missing?

Comment: you must first install homebrew in your system. read this link: https://docs.brew.sh/Installation

Comment: It installed correctly, but I'm still getting this error: ```java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver```

Comment: add mysql dependency. i will update my answer

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got a bit further now - the ```ClassNotFoundException``` has dissapeared, but now there is ```com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure``` in its place :/ I updated my question with my code, since maybe there is an error there?

Comment: you must check mariadb or mysql is install in your system. use this link : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-mariadb-on-macos-using-homebrew/

Answer (score 0):

If you use Maven when creating new project, you could use as @SMD suggestion to add dependency with right clicking in dependency folder and add dependency

- groupId : com.mysql
- artifactId : mysql-connector-j
- version : 8.0.33
  [image: adding dependency when using maven]

If you using Java Ant, you should add the jar libraries by right clicking in the libraries, add library or Jar/Folder. This is when interesting happened, the libraries is works when you add import java.sql and so on, but it would give you Java.lang.classNotFoundException.
The next thing you do is to edit the libraries by right clicking libraries folder, and click Properties. Then move the library up, from class path into ModulePath.
[image: Moving library from classpath into modulPath]

and thats it, clean and build and then run your application